# about how much memory needed to allow my db to be an "in memory" db?

Tags: mysql

I have one database with 3 tables. Each table has this basic structure:

```
id = varchar(64)    
title = varchar(256)  
document =  varchar(12800)
```

the table sizes are:

```
table #1 = 50,000 rows  
table #2 = 40,000 rows  
table #3 = 15,000 rows
```

I want to query those tables as fast as absolutely possible. I will never need to write to those tables. So, I will be experimenting with an "in memory" database.

I am using a MacBook Pro, 2.5-GHz Ivy Bridge, with 4-GB RAM, OSX Mountain Lion. I plan to use MySQL. Is 4-GB more than enough? I mean, I don't want to risk getting errors only because of a lack of memory.

*On a related topic*...
I just replaced my 500-GB HDD with with a 250-GB SSD. If partitioning across the SSD and HDD has a chance of making read access faster, I'll make the effort to move the HDD over to the optical drive bay. Should I experiment with partitioning between SSD and HDD for read only access?

Comment: You also have to consideration what database engine or table types you are using, indexes, other things that use memory like temporary tables, key buffers, caches...

Comment: Try checking out embedded databases like H2 DB. They are optimized for read-only queries. Might help you out.